# Find 2nd highest number in selection then display adjacent cell (includes duplicates) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

So I've got a few rows with data. Row 8 with Names, Row 9 with money amounts and Row 3 with ranking number. You can see via the photo. I'd like D4 to scan Row 9 for the highest money number then display the name above the highest number. D5 would be 2nd highest money amount and so on.

Now I was able to solve this with `=INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(LARGE($B$1:$B$6,D1),$B$1:$B$6,0))` but this doesn't work with duplicates which I have. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: soooo, what should happen with duplicates then? Showing your expected output is always helpful

Comment: Ideally it would show both duplicates or cut a random one off if it's. Hard to describe since there might be multiple scenarios in how Excel interprets duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a subscription to Office 365 we can use SORT and INDEX.

Put this in D4:

```
=INDEX(SORT(D8:I9,2,-1,TRUE),1,{1,2,3})
```

And Excel will spill the results.

[image]